# SQL alchemy with query

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to get below query in sqlalchemy. I tried using select_from, but that just adds extra from (both table and first select). Please let me know how can this be done.

```
WITH filtered_users AS (
  SELECT
    user.id,
    user.name,
    user.status,
  FROM user
    WHERE user.status = 'ACTIVE'
    ORDER BY user.created_at DESC
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0)
SELECT
    filtered_users.id,
    filtered_users.name,
    filtered_users.status,
    account.id AS id_2
FROM filtered_users
    LEFT JOIN account ON user.account_id = account.id
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried querying it with raw sql? you can do it with **.execute()**

```
db.session.execute(«select from * mytable»)
```